# WPF DefaultButton not working as expected

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following set of controls on a form:

[image]

Each of them is a separate user control, and buttons are set to `IsDefault="True"`.

When typing in the "Quick Search" textbox and pressing enter, the focus jumps from this control to the "..." button on "CDV check".

[image]

How is this possible? Am I missing something or is this a problem within WPF?

Thanx

Comment: why are you setting all the buttons to be Default if you only want Quick Search button to react to Enter key?

Comment: Have a look at this blog post: http://neilmosafi.blogspot.co.uk/2007/04/default-buttons-in-wpf-and-multiple.html

Comment: @AbZy All of them should be default, if and when the control is focussed. In other word when I am typing in Quick Search, that button should be default, but when typing in Barcode that button should be Default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using style triggers , please look at the sample xaml below. if you want you can move the style common to the resources.

```
<GroupBox Header="GroupBox1"
          Height="100"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Margin="35,49,0,0"
          Name="GroupBox1"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Width="247">
  <Grid>
    <TextBox Height="23"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             Margin="10,30,0,0"
             x:Name="TextBox1"
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Width="120" />

    <Button Content="Button1"
            Height="23"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="136,29,0,0"
            Name="Button1"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Width="75">
      <Button.Style>
        <Style  TargetType="Button">
          <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TextBox1, Path=IsFocused }"
                         Value="True">
              <Setter Property="IsDefault"
                      Value="True"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
      </Button.Style>
    </Button>
  </Grid>
</GroupBox>
<GroupBox Header="GroupBox2"
          Height="98"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Margin="35,155,0,0"
          Name="GroupBox2"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Width="247">
  <Grid>
    <TextBox Height="23"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             Margin="10,29,0,0"
             x:Name="TextBox2"
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Width="120" />
    <Button Content="Button"
            Height="23"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="136,29,0,0"
            Name="Button2"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Width="75">
      <Button.Style>
        <Style  TargetType="Button">
          <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TextBox2, Path=IsFocused }"
                         Value="True">
              <Setter Property="IsDefault"
                      Value="True"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
      </Button.Style>
    </Button>
  </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `FocusManager.IsFocusScope="true"` on each of the parent layout controls.